# I am getting error when passing the value from csv data set config but it’s working when hard coded value is used

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, amqp

I am using jmeter csv data set configuration to pass the value dynamically in amqp publisher. Script is working fine when using the hard coded value but when using csv data set config value is passing correctly as per requirement but getting error in the component saying unrecognized escape character d , but if the same value is hard coded it’s not giving any error in the component

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a plugin - you need to specify which exactly as we're not telepathic enough to guess. Normally looking at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) helps to detect the root cause for any misbehaviour. You might need to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) to see it however. And also normally you should reach out to the plugins author(s) with the questions like this.

This line in *log4j2.xml* file sets JMeter's log level to DEBUG (it will give ** a lot** of output.

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter" level="debug" />
```

you might want to add a similar to raise [logging level](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/apache/log4j/Level.html) for the plugin you're using.